# Given YYYY-MM-DD, how to find start date of week & end date of week?

Tags: linux, bash, date, scripting

Is there a way to use the date function in linux to get the exact date of the start of the week & end of the week for a given YYYY-MM-DD?

For example, I could enter `2020-07-24` and it would return `2020-07-20` (Monday) & `2020-07-26` (Sunday) as start & end date for this particular week respectively.

Comment: Yes there is a way but not directly. Have you tried anything? A good place to start would be to read the [date manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) and see what options it has. In particular it can tell you the current day of the week with `+%u` and from that you can do some calculations and use `--date='X days ago'` (as an example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112772/get-monday-and-sunday-etc-for-a-week-for-any-date-as-parameter-in-unix

Answer (score 0):

This shell script should work on most Linux as mostly they use GNU date

It converts the input to epoch seconds and then goes back a day until Monday is
found

```
#!/bin/bash

# take the parameter from command line
d="$1"

# find the current time as seconds since 1st Jan 1970 (epoch time)
start=$(date -d "$d" '+%s')

consider="$start"

# day of the week for the time we are considering
dow=$(date -d "@$consider" '+%A')

# is the day of the week monday?  if not, carry on
while [[ "$dow" != "Monday" ]]; do

# adjust the time to be a day further in the past, 24*60*60 seconds is 1 day
  let "consider=$consider - 86400"
  dow=$(date -d "@$consider" '+%A')
done

# output the found date
date -d "@$consider"
```